# IOS - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a9a2c0'

Tags: ios, audio

I'm very new to ios developing, and i don't really undertand yet the errors that console shows.

This is the error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NVViewController Play:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a9a2c0'**

I put my code below, the error occurs when I touch the Play Button.

```
#import "NVViewController.h"

@implementation NVViewController

@synthesize reproductor;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError* error;

    NSString* ruta = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BackgroundMusic" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:ruta];

    self.reproductor = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

    [self.reproductor prepareToPlay];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playBackgroundMusic:(id)sender {
    [self.reproductor play];
}

- (IBAction)stopBackgroundMusic:(id)sender {
    [self.reproductor stop];
}
@end
```

and the header.

```
@interface NVViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong) AVAudioPlayer * reproductor;

- (IBAction)playBackgroundMusic:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopBackgroundMusic:(id)sender;

@end
```

Thanks.

Comment: try to put self.reproductor = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error]; in playBackgroundMusic before [self.reproductor play];

Comment: I would suggest just trying [reproductor play]; instead of self. For some reason your code is calling a method on NIViewController (self) instead of the AVAudioPlayer Object.

Comment: You should put code from NVViewController that is also using self.reproductor because somewhere else your might be setting self.reproductor to a NVViewController object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code (elsewhere), you called `Play:` on your view controller instead of `playBackgroundMusic:`. The error message clearly states that you sent `Play:` to an `NVViewController` instead which didn't understand that message.